# How to invoke a public method depending on a certain instance property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, es6-class, subclassing

I'm learning Typescript and I'm trying to run method in a class.
I have a Class Person, and two classes which extends the Person Class: Man and Woman.

I also have an array of persons, and I need returns hello man! or hello woman! if person is a man or if is a woman.

This is my code:

```
abstract class Person {
    static population: number = 0;
    constructor() {
        Person.population ++ ;
    }
}

class Man extends Person {
    age!: number;

    constructor(age: number) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
    }

    public helloMan() {
        console.log('Hello Man!');
    }
}

class Woman extends Person {
    age!: number;

    constructor(age: number) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
    }

    public helloWoman() {
        console.log('Hello Woman!');
    }
}

let persons: Person[] = [];
persons.push(new Man(24));
persons.push(new Woman(27));
persons.push(new Man(42));
persons.push(new Woman(35));

for(let person of persons){

    let typeOfPerson = Object.getPrototypeOf(person).constructor.name;
    switch (typeOfPerson) {
        case "Man":
            // run helloMan method
            break;
    
        case "Woman":
            // run helloWoman method
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

¿How I can run the method of each gender?

expected result:

```
Hello Man!
Hello Woman!
Hello Man!
Hello Woman!
```

Comment: Isn't it better to define an abstract method `hello` in `Person` and implement it in both descendants? That way you don't need to determine an actual class of a Person instance

Comment: An "if" with a type guard would be way better than Object.getPrototypeOf which is really from a different fairytale here.

Comment: @dryant ... 1/2 ... As *Anatoly* already did mention the entire purpose of inheritance is code-reuse, therefore it does not make any sense to implement  two gender specific salutation methods (like with `helloWoman` / `helloMan`). The OP her/himself treats `Woman`/`Man` instances as `Person` types. Thus the OP wants to somehow have implemented a generic `hello` method which then returns the correct result from each gender specific context.

Comment: @dryant ... 2/2 ... And for the OP's current solution where one needs to figure out a person instance's gender via `instanceof` one does not need a `Person` class at all since it gets exclusively used as namespace which features a sole `population` count where the value gets incremented with every instantiation.

Comment: @dryant ... Regarding the code refactoring of the 2nd but late provided answer are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) here:

```
if (person instanceof Man) {
    person.helloMan()
} else if (person instanceof Woman) {
    person.helloWoman()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The beneath provided refactored hybrid JavaScript/TypeScript version of the OP's originally provided TypeScript implementation comes with a modeling which now justifies the existence of a `Person` class more than what got provided with the question.

The modeling provided by the OP was neither in need of a `Person` class nor of inheritance at all. The explanation was already given with my above 2 comments ...

> *"@dryant ... 1/2 ... As *Anatoly* already did mention the entire purpose of inheritance is code-reuse, therefore it does not make any sense to implement  two gender specific salutation methods (like with `helloWoman` / `helloMan`). The OP her/himself treats `Woman`/`Man` instances as `Person` types. Thus the OP wants to somehow have implemented a generic `hello` method which then returns the correct result from each gender specific context."*

> *"@dryant ... 2/2 ... And for the OP's current solution where one needs to figure out a person instance's gender via `instanceof` one does not need a `Person` class at all since it gets exclusively used as namespace which features a sole `population` count where the value gets incremented with every instantiation."*

[The beneath code's TypeScript pendant runs at typescriptlang.org's Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/PTAEGMHsFcDsBdQEsDOoAOAnS8Cm48ATUAIwE9QBbSQ6AG11BSnVwFgAoBxdSdegIbwkkWAGEYCAFyhY0SiVyZQAXlAAGANydOAkiniYBBCHQEo0ABSUpRoAN46OoUAGIA5rliElMg5iRYd21nNwFPGTkFJRCXVxQBOmh4IRFYP0NA4KcXKFh-aAJITAAKR1CXT28lVVAAclgcDGwANyQfQjqAGk4XF3DGNQBaAEYeiqZE5NS7NTqACVw6OkgAQm7e0ABfAEoHTZdefjNhUQk4eABqS5CD0HgAC1QAOg8vH2U1Ko-YvseX1wDWpAgB8anUoAA-KAgTJRr8XP8UK8EkkUqdYLVUdMMb8tptPIhvkoSjsMgEgvsJphcPBoJhMUjXsTMHiCbSYZ5SZF5IpMAAfOTLKl9UA0ukM+5PZGAzygMEaKFSgGw2T0Ohs0IPJYrUDc0AtSDtEV9PK2BjPFbuEpM+JTdFpHaalwgUBDWS4JCPGoCUAAA2smFssD9yHyKVg4EYjWU3v9geDfs2rtyZgsyHgKCWADMmA8YHRiNncEJ6YxfVg+Ep4BRismwC5KLT80XiqBcAAPXgoLJSxhHQQYiCSeDPetuvugE54ZQlnt0CjgASYxQw8BPXAtXDEcgw2Dj-qEQhetKJBftrvFIigbNwAhpYBNx40MccfEcTjgNNoADqkEoy4Xng3hWDYdjlLkogFEUpT2JygxumMkxojMmJzIsyyQKAf4AbA6zbHsEF9Cg0CsLBoAsjIdTFgBDDdP0nhdMhOJpARmrvl+5hoAAsoBnbAYQoFBuBmxmoYhTwMUZTwbUoxMdiDqzPUGG6rxeF1ARJouCRZHSZR9S0bg9EDPJ9qoWxmzvu+n5QTwYH5LUADamywLgADu2H-su0kDDIADMACsBHjC4rkeTh3lwb5oAAEwAOzBS57mgGpPkRKAAAsMWJaEYUpZF8EyDFGU5QAuiEZqQBaVrSRgfCDmk5wIBZH4cNmbYlGJGD2aAkC5mRwYoIRmwDaIzzaphpK-JV1WQNazmtaK0k0YkuBURFsAADp1Cg9GGVRanbbtuyOaNsDPCypVQtCdQJqIR0bBMdRAqgj2imdzwmTkoClc8ABWRqwCUGl1DsOycFsQA)

```js
// also see ... typescriptlang.org ... TypeScript Playground
// [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/PTAEGMHsFcDsBdQEsDOoAOAnS8Cm48ATUAIwE9QBbSQ6AG11BSnVwFgAoBxdSdegIbwkkWAGEYCAFyhY0SiVyZQAXlAAGANydOAkiniYBBCHQEo0ABSUpRoAN46OoUAGIA5rliElMg5iRYd21nNwFPGTkFJRCXVxQBOmh4IRFYP0NA4KcXKFh-aAJITAAKR1CXT28lVVAAclgcDGwANyQfQjqAGk4XF3DGNQBaAEYeiqZE5NS7NTqACVw6OkgAQm7e0ABfAEoHTZdefjNhUQk4eABqS5CD0HgAC1QAOg8vH2U1Ko-YvseX1wDWpAgB8anUoAA-KAgTJRr8XP8UK8EkkUqdYLVUdMMb8tptPIhvkoSjsMgEgvsJphcPBoJhMUjXsTMHiCbSYZ5SZF5IpMAAfOTLKl9UA0ukM+5PZGAzygMEaKFSgGw2T0Ohs0IPJYrUDc0AtSDtEV9PK2BjPFbuEpM+JTdFpHaalwgUBDWS4JCPGoCUAAA2smFssD9yHyKVg4EYjWU3v9geDfs2rtyZgsyHgKCWADMmA8YHRiNncEJ6YxfVg+Ep4BRismwC5KLT80XiqBcAAPXgoLJSxhHQQYiCSeDPetuvugE54ZQlnt0CjgASYxQw8BPXAtXDEcgw2Dj-qEQhetKJBftrvFIigbNwAhpYBNx40MccfEcTjgNNoADqkEoy4Xng3hWDYdjlLkogFEUpT2JygxumMkxojMmJzIsyyQKAf4AbA6zbHsEF9Cg0CsLBoAsjIdTFgBDDdP0nhdMhOJpARmrvl+5hoAAsoBnbAYQoFBuBmxmoYhTwMUZTwbUoxMdiDqzPUGG6rxeF1ARJouCRZHSZR9S0bg9EDPJ9qoWxmzvu+n5QTwYH5LUADamywLgADu2H-su0kDDIADMACsBHjC4rkeTh3lwb5oAAEwAOzBS57mgGpPkRKAAAsMWJaEYUpZF8EyDFGU5QAuiEZqQBaVrSRgfCDmk5wIBZH4cNmbYlGJGD2aAkC5mRwYoIRmwDaIzzaphpK-JV1WQNazmtaK0k0YkuBURFsAADp1Cg9GGVRanbbtuyOaNsDPCypVQtCdQJqIR0bBMdRAqgj2imdzwmTkoClc8ABWRqwCUGl1DsOycFsQA]

// count is protected by module scope
let populationCount/*: number*/ = 0;

/*abstract */class Person {

  #gender/*: string*/;
  #age/*: number*/;
  #salutation/*: string*/;

  constructor({
    gender = 'not provided',
    age = -1,
    salutation = 'Hello!',
  }) {
    populationCount++;

    this.#gender = gender;
    this.#age = age >= 0 ? age : -1;
    this.#salutation = salutation;
  }
  get gender()/*: string*/ {
    return this.#gender;
  }
  get age()/*: number|null*/ {
    return this.#age >= 0 ? this.#age : null;
  }
  hello ()/*: void*/ {
    console.log(this.#salutation);
  }
  // - neither a `Person` instance nor the `Person`
  //   class itself should feature a property or
  //   method for exposing the population count.
  // - the latter easily can be achieved by an
  //   additionally exported function/method.
}

class Woman extends Person {
  constructor({ age = -1, salutation = 'Hello Woman!' }) {
    super({ gender: 'female',  age, salutation });
  }
}
class Man extends Person {
  constructor({ age = -1, salutation = 'Hello Man!' }) {
    super({ gender: 'male', age, salutation });
  }
}

const persons = [
  new Woman({ age: 35 }),
  new Woman({ age: 27 }),
  new Man({ age: 42 }),
  new Man({ age: 24 }),
];
console.log({  populationCount });

for (const person of persons) {
  person.hello();
  console.log([

    ({ female: 'Woman\'s', male: 'Man\'s'})[person.gender] ?? 'Person\'s',
    'age is',
    person.age,

  ].join(' '))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```